# How to get unique row with multiple rows from other table in one column?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an SQL query to get the users records along with their latest two comments in one column.

The tables structure and sample data are like this:

**`users` table**

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vanesh | vanesh@test.com |
| 2 | Ganesh | ganesh@test.com |
| 3 | Ramesh | ramesh@test.com |
| 4 | Shyam | shyam@test.com |

**`user_comments` table**

| id | user_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | comment 1 |
| 2 | 1 | comment 2 |
| 3 | 2 | comment 3 |
| 4 | 2 | comment 4 |
| 5 | 3 | comment 5 |
| 6 | 3 | comment 6 |
| 7 | 1 | comment 7 |
| 8 | 2 | comment 8 |
| 9 | 2 | comment 9 |
| 10 | 4 | comment 10 |

I have tried this query to get what I am looking for but it is still half-baked:

```
with cteRowNumber as (
    select users.id, users.name, users.email, user_id, comment, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by user_id order by user_comments.id desc) as RowNum
        from user_comments
        join users on users.id = user_comments.user_id
)
select user_id, name, email, comment
    from cteRowNumber
    where RowNum <= 2
    group by user_id, comment
```

It gives output like this:

| user_id | name | email | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vanesh | vanesh@test.com | comment 7 |
| 1 | Vanesh | vanesh@test.com | comment 2 |
| 2 | Ganesh | ganesh@test.com | comment 9 |
| 2 | Ganesh | ganesh@test.com | comment 8 |
| 3 | Ramesh | ramesh@test.com | comment 6 |
| 3 | Ramesh | ramesh@test.com | comment 5 |
| 4 | Shyam | shyam@test.com | comment 10 |

**What I am looking for is something like this -**

| user_id | name | email | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vanesh | vanesh@test.com | comment 7, comment 2 |
| 2 | Ganesh | ganesh@test.com | comment 9, comment 8 |
| 3 | Ramesh | ramesh@test.com | comment 6, comment 5 |
| 4 | Shyam | shyam@test.com | comment 10 |

Comment: You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` or similar, and that depends on the specific database. What database are you using?

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

- generate the ranking value for each user with descendent comment id
- keep the first two comments with a filtering operation (`rn <= 2`)
- aggregate your comments
- join back to the users table

This is an example in MySQL:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
    FROM user_comments
)
SELECT cte.user_id AS user_id,
       u.name      AS user_name,
       u.email     AS user_email,
       GROUP_CONCAT(comment_ ORDER BY cte.id DESC) AS user_comment
FROM       cte
INNER JOIN users u
        ON cte.user_id = u.id
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY user_id,
         user_name,
         user_email
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6erTfjYbgNjf9udFf1botq/1).